How to justify a ban on exclusivist religions?
Certain religions are known for fervent persecution of other faiths and/or non-standard lifestyles. In a satirical reversal, the target society is going to persecute such religions with the same fervor. This is a modern-day, alt-history setting, with a US-style quasi-democratic government, but where the US had Anglo-Saxon Protestants, it has Scandinavian Pagans.
I need to create an Act, which will contain 1) a very solid, rationally sounding justification for this, and 2) a clear definition of what is being banned, better than "I know it when I see it".
The true in-universe reason for the law is revenge for persecution, and perhaps paranoia that it might happen again. But the act should be phrased as if it's simply protecting universal self-evident principles.
The target result is that Paganism, Buddhism, Shinto, Hinduism, Wicca, and other polytheistic religions are allowed. Ones that strongly discriminate against non-believers, forbidden. The target religious landscape of the nation is belief in deities from multiple traditions simultaneously coexisting, in a Marvel Cinematic Universe sort of way.
The challenges are:

The more bona-fide it sounds, the better. "Deity anti-discrimination act" has a nice ring to it.
It can't be easily bypassed by changing deity names.
But it can't require Buddhists or followers of only one pagan god to worship multiple deities.
It can't be contingent on on actual hostile acts; no [un]holy book should cross the border.
It's satire, so turning the church's or the inquisition's logic on them would be perfect!

What would be a good way to phrase such a worldview and justify such a ban?
I've thought of claiming belief in strictly hereditary godhood as monarchical and antithetical to democracy or meritocracy, but most pagan religions do have it hereditary. A single-deity rule would target the very pagan free choice of one god to worship out of many. Targeting religions that discriminate against other deities might be a sensible approach, but it has to target specifically de-deifying them, rather than simply choosing Loki over Thor.
Can such a line be drawn, and if so, how?
P.S. This isn't meant to raise the question of whether monotheism leads to persecution and religious wars. It's a fictional scenario where similar persecution is employed against historically-dominant religions.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Monotheism is too positively branded. How about exclusivist faith?
Thank you for contacting the Congressional Record. Please find attached the text of the The Theological Inclusivity and Divine Recognition Act of 2045.

Section 1: Definitions.
(a) "Exclusivist faith" shall mean any religion
or belief system that asserts the existence of its own deity or
deities while explicitly denying the existence of other divinities.
(b) "State-recognized divinities" shall refer to the pantheon of gods,
goddesses, and divine beings officially acknowledged by the government
as defined in the Divine Recognition Act of 2030 and its subsequent
amendments.
Section 2: Prohibition.
(a) It shall be unlawful for any person,
organization, or institution to practice, promote, or propagate any
exclusivist faith that explicitly denies the existence of
state-recognized divinities.
(b) Any faith that acknowledges the
potential existence of multiple divinities and of the plurality of state-recognized deities, regardless of its focus of
worship, shall not be subject to this prohibition, in accordance with
the Religious Plurality Protection Act of 2035.
Section 3: Enforcement.
(a) Any individual found in violation of
Section 2 shall be subject to penalties as outlined in the Theological
Crimes and Misdemeanors Act of 2040.
(b) Organizations or institutions
found in violation may face consequences as detailed in the
Institutional Religious Compliance Statute of 2042.
Section 4: Religious Freedom Clause.
This Act does not prohibit the
private, non-proselytizing practice of personal religious beliefs,
provided such practices do not explicitly deny the existence of
state-recognized divinities in public forums or official capacities,
as stipulated in the Personal Faith Protection Amendment of 2043.
Section 5: Compliance with International Standards.
This Act adheres to
the principles set forth in the Global Theological Harmony Treaty of
2043, to which our nation is a signatory.
Section 6: Review and Update Procedures.
The list of state-recognized
divinities shall be reviewed and updated every five years by the
National Divine Recognition Committee, as established by the Divine
Recognition Act of 2030, to ensure continued relevance and
inclusivity.


Brrr............... you could become some political horror writer

You win. This is beautiful. Possibly one of the best answers to WB I have ever seen.

You might need to amend the first and second sections - some Christian denominations consider deities from other religions to be demons (not other gods), not that whatever being doesn't exist.  Also, you might want to consider D&D-adjacent style beliefs, where one religion may claim that some portion of another religion is really an aspect of their own...

@Clockwork-Muse While your concern is understandable, I would refer you to the Theological Interpretation and Classification Act of 2037, which already addresses these nuances. Section 4(b) of that Act specifically defines "denial of existence" to include reclassification of state-recognized divinities as demons, lesser spirits, or aspects of other deities.

@Clockwork-Muse As for the latter point, as long as the faith practitioners or organizations do not deny the existence of a state-recognized deity, nor deny its nature, the aforementioned Personal Faith Protection Amendment of 2043 offers generous leeway for interpretations of how those deities should be grouped and worshipped.

Atheists are not going to feel the love here.

@candied_orange: What do you mean?  Atheism doesn't "asserts the existence of its own deity or deities" so it's not an "exclusivist faith" as defined in 1(a), so this law doesn't prohibit promotion of atheism as a belief system.

@PeterCordes 2a "explicitly denies the existence of state-recognized divinities." That's pretty much all they do. If you think they don't you're thinking of agnostics.

@candied_orange: 2(a) only prohibits promotion of an exclusivist faith which denies existence of state divinities, not just denial.  Atheism is not an "exclusivist faith" according to the definition in 1(a), so 2(a) doesn't apply to it.  Of course I'm just lawyering the law as written here.  It could very easily be amended (either in-world or by an author before publishing a story) to also cover atheism, depending on what story they want to tell.

@PeterCordes that’s the problem. They’re not recognized as a belief system and if they were they’d be law breakers. Thus not feeling the love.

@candied_orange: What?  I don't see most atheists getting upset over not being considered an "exclusivist faith" according to the definition in 1(a) which all the later clauses refer to.  The whole point of rational atheism is that blind faith is a problem.  Atheism clearly is a "belief system", and this law doesn't dispute that.  But since it doesn't "assert the existence of its own deity or deities", it's not one of the belief systems that this law bans.  IDK if you're still focused on 2(a) while ignoring its reference to the definition of "exclusivist faith" in 1(a)?

@PeterCordes So while other recognized faiths enjoy the protection of the law the Atheists must be content that their non existent Gods existence isn't recognized or protected. Sorry, still don't feel the love.

@candied_orange - You were hoping that a nation with some state-endorsed religions would also explicitly endorse atheism as an approved and encouraged belief-system?  It seems totally fine to me that their law against other forms of religion clearly avoids prohibiting atheism at all, and doesn't even stop people from promoting atheism to others.  Were you hoping for this law to ban trying to convert atheists to other religions?  IDK why that would be necessary or helpful.  They obviously wouldn't stop people from trying to convert atheists to one of the approved religions.

@candied_orange - to me it seems like this wording carefully carves out an exception for atheism as one of the only belief systems that's allowed to deny the existence of the state-recognized divinities.  (Other belief systems that involve no gods could also be allowed by this phrasing, like perhaps Jedi belief in the Force?  And other mysticism type of beliefs perhaps in spirits of nature.  The in-world-historic problem they're trying to fix has involved monotheistic one-true-god religions so it's still serving its purpose.)

@candied_orange: So this seems totally fine to me for a progressive and democratic society.  IDK what kind of phrasing or new clauses you would hope for in this to show some "love" to atheism.  Like what more do you want beyond not being banned?  And why do you want more?  A law trying to fix a problem of monotheist zealotry against polytheistic religions doesn't seem to need to say anything to promote atheism, that wasn't the problem.

I am unable to provide specific commentary on interpretation, as this department is solely a reference resource and cannot offer statements of a political nature. A different department so empowered might direct your attention to Evers v. NDRC (2046)  where the majority opinion stated “individuals who do not profess the existence of any deity are not subject to the Act’s restrictions, as is plainly evident from the wording of Section 1(a), which concerns only belief systems that assert the existence of a deity while denying others.” This ruling may provide the clarity you seek.

Monotheism is Subversive
Cæsar Eleison
There's no need to reinvent the wheel; the Romans already answered your question two thousand years ago.
When the Roman Empire was going through its first few big expansionist phases, they came across a slight hiccup: all the different areas they conquered, while still more-or-less polytheistic pagans, worshiped slightly different pantheons. Rather than try to overwrite the local cults with the True Roman ReligionTM—something that was guaranteed to result in a bloodbath—they took a different tack. Subject kingdoms were allowed to keep their own religions—as long as they added the Emperor to their pantheon. While this was initially merely a form of pragmatism on the Romans' part, they quickly came to perceive the Emperor's divinity as a core part of their empire's stability. Whether it actually was is a matter of some debate.[1]
Most of the time, this worked pretty well; paganism tends to be pretty open to accepting new deities of dubious provenance, and most monotheistic religions of the time were very mystic (which tends to result in a certain propensity for syncretism.) The main exceptions were Judaism and later Christianity, both of which are very clear that there is one God, and no other. In the case of Judaism, the Romans chose to turn a blind eye to it; its practitioners were heavily concentrated in one area with little interest in spreading to the rest of the Empire, so they could afford to leave them alone.
However, in the case of Christianity, it very quickly spread throughout the whole Roman Empire, and was especially popular with the slaves, noncitizens, and commoners—a demographic which throughout history has been the backbone of revolutions. Thus, Rome cracked down on those who did not acknowledge Cæsar as Lord, enacting laws requiring all subjects to have a notarized form to the effect that they had made ritual sacrifices to the Emperor, on pain of death.[2] The extent to which these were enforced varied depending on the current regime; some Emperors (Nero, Decius, etc.) strictly enforced them, while others (such as Galerius) let enforcement slide.

[1]: See Augustine (426) The City of God.
[2]: There were other components, but going into all of it would add considerable unneeded complexity to the answer. TL;DR: Monotheism = capital offense.

And yet the Roman Emperor ultimately became the leader of the Christian (Roman Catholic) church, and became in essence the same as God in his powers (the word of the Holy Roman Emperor was essentially the Word of God). There really was no difference between the God of the Roman Catholic Church and the Holly Roman Emperor (later to become the Holly Roman Pope, a continuity that still exists today). Strange turn of events, that.

@JustinThymetheSecond While such an incident would be quite funny, the reverse is what actually happened. The Roman Empire collapsed, there were ~300 years of anarchy, and then the Franks started to put things back together. The Pope, being the Pope, then declared Charlemagne the "Holy Roman Emperor" as a way to secure the Papacy's hold over the new empire. I'm Protestant for a reason; among other things, while the Protestant movement sometimes gets a little too non-bureaucratic, it does generally acknowledge at least some separation of Church and State.

@JustinThymetheSecond Also, while the Holy Roman Emperor did benefit from a somewhat overly-broad interpretation of the Divine Right of Kings (...but that's a whole theological can of worms for another day), there very much was a difference between God and the Emperor. People were expected to pay fealty to him as the ordained ruler, but he was not considered infallible, and his words did not carry divine weight.

The Roman Empire as a political/geographic entity collapsed, but it still lives on just as strong in the Roman Catholic Church. They are one and the same, one evolved from the other. The Pope is in all respects a continuation of the line of Roman Emperors. Historically, that can not be disputed. Contrary to your assertion, the Roman Emperor under the Roman Empire DID regard himself as "God. Not Divine Right of Kings, but a manifestation of God himself. The Roman Catholic Pope is a direct descendant of this line of control.

There are many (Opus Die) who still believe the Roman Empire will be resurrected through the Roman Catholic Church and the world domination of the Roman Emperor will prevail.

See https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/studies-in-church-history/article/abs/popes-as-rulers-of-rome-in-the-aftermath-of-empire-476769/5DFFE5309304CA14B9B876B12B4096E4 for example

Thou shalt honor all Gods and not put one before the other.


a very solid, rationally sounding justification for this,


Dishonoring a God dishonors the followers of that God and harms all followers of any God.


a clear definition of what is being banned,


Pursuit of ones faith must not tread upon the faith of others. Faith may only be used to better ones self. It may not be used to forcibly improve others.
This is how it began. Later revisions changed "God" to "God / Tenants" and so on until it all became hard to read and soon people could argue it meant anything they wanted. And so they did.

Outlaw any religions whose equivalent of a Bible advocates violence to other religions or puts itself above secular law. This allows you to send in the armed forces to quell any uprising or demonstrations. And go straight for the head, make the leaders responsible.
You can't do it by monotheism, all religions can rationalise as polytheism. Eg. Catholicism prays to Saints and the Virgin Mary as well as God & Jesus etc,.
Make all religious institutions register as businesses and open to the same fee's and most importantly laws thus removing protection of their leaders from a lot of potential legal problems.
The important bit is to actively enforce this. Religious leaders will soon toe the line when it's their necks on the chopping block, not their brainwashed followers. By making the leaders responsible for the acts of their followers, no one will be keen on leading and the religion will die out organically.

"All religions can rationalise as polytheism": Sunni Islam, for example, is very much purely monotheistic. There is no God but God, and there are no other figures which could be interpreted as gods.

@
AlexP
The Satanic Verses. Any time a religion professes  'God' as a subset of 'Everything', and professes something that  is outside of this subset 'God', that is, a region of this domain that is 'Not God', such as 'Evil' or 'The Devil' or 'Satan's Realm', is no longer strictly monotheistic. Any religion that states 'God' is the entire domain 'Everything' no longer allows for anything that is 'Not God', or 'Against God'. The Satanic Paradox.

Pretty much every religion puts itself above secular law, and (as religious extremists the world over have proven) "kill the infidels" isn't an exclusively monotheistic practice.

@AlexP there's  no such thing as people who won't rationalise whatever is necessary to survive as a group. Some individuals might go hard but they're the ones you feed to the lions pour encourager les autres.

"...Making the leaders responsible for the acts of their followers" has been tried already, and there are still monotheistic faiths, among whose adherents there are still leaders.

@Conrado not in some places. It's all in the enforcement.

@AlexP nonsense, Sunni has shaitan and a host of others that can be interpreted any way necessary to fit an agenda

Please excuse the plagiarism of another answer, I prefer to think of it as 'appropriation".
Thank you for contacting the Congressional Record. Please find attached the text of the The Theological Exclusivity and Recognition of the State Act of 2045.
Section 1: Definitions.
(a) "Exclusivist faith" shall mean any religion or belief system that asserts the existence of its own deity or deities and/or incorporates in its ideology and theology any admonishment that does not recognize the State as the supreme authority over people and the State as the sole arbiter of lawful, ethical, and moral behavior.
(b) "State-recognized institutions" shall refer to the pantheon of social policy, economic, educational, legal, health care, gubernatorial, and political institutions officially acknowledged by the government as arbiters of human behavior defined in the Ideology Recognition Act of 2030 and its subsequent amendments.
(c) "Approved Faith Governance Organization" shall refer to any organization that professes, proselytizes, promotes, practices, or administers a Faith-based Ideology that is in accordance with the Faith Recognition Act of 2030 and approved by the Faith Recognition Review Committee.
Section 2: Prohibition.
(a) It shall be unlawful for any person, organization, or institution to practice, promote, admonish, proselytize for, or propagate any Exclusivist faith that explicitly denies the authority of state-recognized institutions to exclusively enact legislation, policies, procedures, or prohibitions the intent of which is to govern, control, regulate, judge, or arbitrate human behavior.
(b) Any faith-based organization that acknowledges the sole and exclusive right of  state-recognized institutions to ultimately govern, punish, monitor, judge, or otherwise dictate, arbitrate, or control human behavior, regardless of its focus of worship, shall not be subject to this prohibition, in accordance with the Religious Exemption and Protection Act of 2035, if it has accreditation as an Approved Faith Governance Organization under the Faith Recognition Act of 2030.
(c) This act shall not apply to the right for a family unit to govern the activities of its members in order to maintain household discipline as long as such governance acknowledges and accedes to the state as the ultimate authority to govern, punish, monitor, arbitrate, judge or otherwise dictate or control human behavior.
Section 3: Enforcement.
(a) Any individual found in violation of Section 2 shall be subject to state  re-education as outlined in the Theological Crimes and Misdemeanors Act of 2040.
(b) Organizations or institutions found in violation may face consequences, including reorganization as detailed in the State Institution Religious and Ideology Compliance Statute of 2042.
Section 4: Religious Freedom Clause.
This Act does not prohibit the private, non-proselytizing practice of personal religious beliefs, provided such practices do not explicitly or implicitly deny the authority of state-recognized institutions in public forums or official capacities, as stipulated in the Personal Faith Protection Amendment of 2043.
Section 5: Compliance with International Standards.
This Act adheres to the principles set forth in the Global Theological Harmony Treaty of 2043, to which our nation is a signatory.
Section 6: Review and Update Procedures.
The list of state-recognized Approved Faith Governance Organizations that are in compliance with this Act shall be reviewed and updated every five years by the National Faith Recognition Review Committee, as established by the Faith Recognition Act of 2030, to ensure continued relevance and inclusivity.

this introduces the problem of the State becoming a de fact "monoteist" cult wrapped around either a mythologized idea of a Nation, or a charismatic Leader. If the State is the Supreme moral Authority, then the President/Leader/Prime Minister/Fuhrer is the Messiah/Pope effectively.

Which is the entire point of my answer - the law of Unintended Consequences. It is a veiled Frame Challenge - there is no way to 'dictate' for or against a religion without doing exactly what the Op wants to eliminate - pitting one religious faction against another, even if the religious faction is paganism - 'One Religion (paganism) above all others'.

In essence, this is exactly how Roman Catholicism started - the Roman Empire under Constantine set Christianity above all other religions, and the result was the persecution of all other religions except the official State religion - even if that religion is 'paganism'. It closely depicts what is current the situation in China.

Since it is satire:
How about ban on monopolies?
Religion, from a government standpoint, is a service. An important one, that is.
Then again, enforcing anti-monopoly legislation over food industry, telecoms, etc... is a hard task and the monopolies thereof have quite a possibilities to fight back.
This is why the administration focus on a business that has little leverage (at some particular moment, but as any temporary measure, the ban on monotheism lasted).

In the Valdemar series of books Mercedes Lackey has a very simple guidance rule: "There is no one true way."
This means that any religion is acceptable as long as they allow all people to have different believes.
Add to that an anti discrimination law which requires female as well as male priests and encourage female as well as male deities, either in the same religion or in two associated religions, you may have the start.
Something like:
As there is no one true way, you may not restrict anybody from believing anything.
To have a religion accepted in this country it has either to have deities of more than one gender and priests, on all levels of priesthood of all genders or it has to have two or more associated branches of religion each allowed to have only one deity but together covering more than one gender, in deity and priesthood.
Adding extra foolsafes (stolen from an other answer) have the highest level priests responsible for what their underlings and the believers do.
A subset of laws can describe what is or isn't allowed but basically the guiding principle No one true way covers all.
